# Can JVM to encounter “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:" despite having sufficient PermSize and OldGen space

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

If application has sufficient space for PermSize and OldGen space, is it sill possible to encounter OutOfMemoryErrors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Perm Gen and Old Gen. JVM may use non-heap memory (e.g. for direct memory buffers).
Amount of non-heap memory is limited by `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` options. If it is exceeded OutOfMemoryError will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Someone in your code base could throw it or Sun  ... er Oracle ;) might throw it. For example look at this code from ByteArrayOutputStream:

```
      /**
       * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
       * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
       *
       * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
       */
      private void grow(int minCapacity) {
           // overflow-conscious code
           int oldCapacity = buf.length;
           int newCapacity = oldCapacity << 1;
           if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
               newCapacity = minCapacity;
           if (newCapacity < 0) {
               if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
                   throw new OutOfMemoryError();
               newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           }
           buf = Arrays.copyOf(buf, newCapacity);
       }
```

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.java.html